# Count the occurrences of strings in matlab with white space?

Tags: string, matlab

So I want to count the number of times a word appears in a string. For example, the number of times the word `hello` appears in the following string:

```
a = "hello my name is helloson or hello this is not a name hello"
```

If I do:

```
count(a,"hello")
```

I get 4, because it includes the `helloson`. I wanted to try to get only the when hello appears as a word so I did:

```
count(a,["hello","hello "," hello ", " hello"])
```

Except that this also gave me 4. Why is this the case? I looked at the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/count.html) and there was nothing said about ignoring whitespace. Why doesn't this work? I thought it was maybe the `["hello"]` included in the array, but trying:

```
count(a,["hello "," hello ", " hello"])
```

Again results in 4. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this issue using [regular expression](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html)

The code I write below will store the hello words in `matchStr` after match the input string `str` with the `expression`. The expression is written in regx and it will do the following comparison, the hello word should come between spaces, a beginning of text followed by space or preceded by space at the end of input.

```
str = "hello my name is helloson , hello or xhello this is not a name hello";

expression = '(\s|^)hello(\s|$)';

matchStr = regexp(str,expression,'match')

length(matchStr)
```

Comment: Was thinking of doing something with regex as well, this is definitely a cleaner solution, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

because "is helloson" contains " hello".

Workaround 1: count(" " + a + " ", " hello ")

Workaround 2: strs = strsplit(a," "); then count how many items in strs are exactly "hello"

Comment: maybe you can do count(" " + a + " ", " hello ")

Comment: Wow, such a simple workaround that I just completely missed, I need to think smarter not harder, thanks!